# Why does VBA say method or data member not found on the initial sub?

Tags: vba

I have tried enabling solver but that didn't seem to work. The error gets thrown at the very first sub in the code saying "data member not found" (Private Sub CmdLaunchStats_Click). I will list my code below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdLaunchStats_Click()

Dim shtThisSheet As Worksheet
Set shtThisSheet = Application.WorksheetFunction

shtThisSheet.Average ("A1:A100")
shtThisSheet.StDev ("A1:A100")
shtThisSheet.Min ("A1:A100")
shtThisSheet.Max ("A1:A100")

Set shtThisSheet.Average("A1:A100") = Average
Set shtThisSheet.StDev("A1:A100") = Standard
Set shtThisSheet.Min("A1:A100") = Min
Set shtThisSheet.Max("A1:A100") = Max

MsgBox Statistics, , False

End Sub
```

Comment: A [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506(v=office.11).aspx) is not a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx). You cannot `Set` a var to the Application.WorksheetFunction object.

Answer (score 2):

A [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506(v=office.11).aspx) is not a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx). You cannot `Set` a var to the Application.WorksheetFunction object.

Further, you cannot `Set` the results of  a worksheet function like the [AVERAGE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6) to an undeclared and unassigned variable; even in reverse.

Your `Option Explicit` states that all variables must be declared before use yet there are no declarations for the Average, Standard, Min and Max vars. It is also considered bad practise to name your vars the same as VBA or worksheet functions or reserved names.

```
Private Sub cmdLaunchStats_Click()
    Dim shtThisSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dAverage As Double, dStandard As Double
    Dim dMin As Double, dMax As Double, sStatistics As String

    Set shtThisSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With shtThisSheet
        With .Range("A1:A100")
            dAverage = Application.Average(.Cells)
            dStandard = Application.StDev(.Cells)
            dMin = Application.Min(.Cells)
            dMax = Application.Max(.Cells)
        End With
    End With
    sStatistics = "average: " & dAverage & Chr(10) & _
                  "standard deviation: " & dStandard & Chr(10) & _
                  "minimum: " & dMin & Chr(10) & _
                  "maximum: " & dMax
    MsgBox sStatistics, , False
End Sub
```

While the full `Application.WorksheetFunction` can be used, typically it is unnecessary. Either `Application.Average(...` or `WorksheetFunction.Average(...` is all that is generally necessary.